# How do I properly Type a mapped React Query request?

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript, react-query

I'm having a hard time properly typing a simple useQuery hook.
I am getting the type error "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'" on `hero.name`. I suspect I need to type `HeroData:[]` more specifically but all my attempts of doing so haven't worked. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import axios from "axios";
interface data {
  HeroData: [];
}

function fetchSuperHeroes(): Promise<HeroData> {
  return axios.get("http://localhost:4000/superheroes");
}

function RQSuperHeroesPage() {
  const { isLoading, data, error } = useQuery({
    queryKey: "super-heroes",
    queryFn: fetchSuperHeroes,
  });

  if (isLoading) {
    return <h2>Loading...</h2>;
  }

  if (error instanceof Error) {
    return <h2>{error.message}</h2>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h2>RQ Super Heroes Page</h2>
      {data?.data.map((hero) => {
        return <div key={hero.name}>{hero.name}</div>;
      })}
    </>
  );
}

export default RQSuperHeroesPage;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're right about the error but there are a few issues with how you're defining the type as well.

```
interface data {
  HeroData: [];
}
```

^ Here you are setting an array as the type for `HeroData`. TypeScript will infer this type as `type HeroData = Array<never>` which basically means it can only ever be an empty array. This is your main problem.

```
function fetchSuperHeroes(): Promise<HeroData> {
  return axios.get("http://localhost:4000/superheroes");
}
```

^ The second issue is that you are only passing `HeroData` into your `ReturnType` definition for your fetcher. This should have actually given you an error in your IDE since `HeroData` does not exist outside of the `data` interface. Further to that, passing `HeroData` as the `ReturnType` doesn't satisfy the way you are parsing the data in your code -- `data.data`.

For future reference, you can grab a type from an interface using the [bracket notation property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

```
type SomePropType = SomeInterface['some_prop'];

// e.g.
type HData = data['HeroData']
```

Now, with that aside here's an approach that should work for you:

```
// Define your Hero type
type Hero = {
  name: string;
  // other hero props here...
}

// Define your HeroData interface
interface HeroData {
  // Define data as an array of type Hero
  data: Hero[];
}

// Use your HeroData interface here so the return matches the
// expected shape `data.data`
function fetchSuperHeroes(): Promise<HeroData> {
  return axios.get("http://localhost:4000/superheroes");
}
```

Hope this helps!